# Add tooltip to TD in DataTable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable for which I bind the data trough JavaScript:

```
$("#TableUsage").DataTable({
                data: infolist(),
                ordering: true,
                paginate: false,
                "info": false,
                columns: [
                    { data: "Product", title: "Product" },
                    { data: "Serial", title: "Serial" },
                    { data: "App", title: "App" },
                ]});
```

The infolist looks something like:

```
infolist.push({Product: "01", Serial: "05", App: "M07", AppCol: "App info P01"})
infolist.push({Product: "02", Serial: "08", App: "M03", AppCol: "App info P02"})
infolist.push({Product: "03", Serial: "03", App: "M09", AppCol: "App info P03"})
```

Usually, in HTML I only write:

```
<td data-bind="text: $data.App, attr: {title: $data.AppCol}">App</td>
```

and the AppCol info is displayed inside a tooltip when hoovering over the App cell value.

Is there a way to add the tooltip, but using Javascript code, because right now, in HTML the table looks like this?

```
<table class="table" style="width: 100%;" id="TableUsage"></table>
```

**UPDATE!**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hg45z9rL/76/) attached :)

Comment: it'd be much easier to help if you can provide us with a working fiddle

Comment: I've added the requested fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so you can do it by defining a render function for your column so you can output HTML for display and return the raw data for sorting/filtering.  You will need to add the following to your DataTable options object:

```
columnDefs: [{
      targets: 2,
      render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
        if(type === 'display') {
           // Return element with title and value.  This is only returned for display
           return '<div title="' + full.AppCol + '">' + data + '</div>';
        }

        // Return raw data for sorting and filtering
        return data;
      }
    }],
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
      //Wire up tool tip here if the library won't automatically pick up new elements.
      // This fires after the draw event is completed so the DataTable is in the DOM
      // With all of it's rows.
    }
```

In the draw callback you can wireup your tooltip library if it won't automatically pickup new grid rows.

Answer (score 0):

I did it a different way from the accepted answer.

My DataTable initialization happens when the page loads, and then I get the data for it afterwards, and then loop through and add the rows one by one.

You can assign the table to a variable, and as you add rows, those can also be variables. You can affect those like you would a jQuery assignment.

```
var dt = $('#isbnTable').DataTable();

Start looping through data {

    var newRow = dt.row.add([
            isbn.isbn,
            isbn.author,
            etc...
    });

    $(newRow).find('td').eq(0).addClass("isbn").attr("title", isbn.status);
    $(newRow).find('td').eq(1).addClass("author").attr("title", isbn.status);
}
```

The .find('td').eq(0) gets you the first td cell. Increase that number (or loop through if you want them all) to affect whichever column you want. I use row.add so I can assign it to a variable and change the classes and attributes. I also add custom classes based on the data to, for instance, change the color of a number cell if it exceeds a certain threshold, or disable inputs if a row is locked.